# Rounding to Significant Figures - Missing Zeros

Tags: javascript, math

I'm currently producing a JavaScript driven mathematics package, which focuses on **rounding** to various **significant figures (S.F.)** but I've run into a problem that I'm struggling to solve.

More on this problem later, but first some background for you.

The program is designed to select a completely *random number* within a given range and then automatically work out that number's relevant *significant figures*; for example:

**Random Number:** `0.097027` **S.Fs:** `9, 7, 0, 2, 7`

---

Here is a screenshot of what I have produced to give you a visual representation:

[image]

As you can see, once the user has selected their number, they are then given the opportunity to click on four separate **'SF' buttons** to view their random number presented to 1, 2, 3 and 4 S.Fs respectively.

For each S.F (1-4) the random number is **rounded down**, **rounded up** and **rounded off** to *X SF* and a scale below gives the user a more visual presentation to show why the SF value has been chosen by the program.

I've already written the vast majority of the code for this and tested it and so far the numbers are coming out how I'm expecting them to. *Well nearly...*

In the example I've given `(0.097027)`; as you can see on the image I've included, the data for 4 S.F is absolutely correct and outputted accurately.

When I click on to the **3 SF** button, I'd expect to see the following:

**Random Number:** `0.097027` **3 S.F Rounded Up/Down/Off:** `0.0970`

However, what I'm actually getting is:

**Random Number:** `0.097027` **3 S.F Rounded Up/Down/Off:** `0.097`

The program hasn't displayed the additional zero. This is a perfect example of a number in my program ending in a zero and in this case the zero is really significant and must be displayed.

---

The data is usually correct but there appears to be an issue with outputting significant zeros at the right time. I've researched the `toFixed(x)` method and if I assign `toFixed(4)` I get the correct required output, but because my numbers are generated randomly each time, they can range from a length of 5 figures, e.g. `89.404` up to > 10, e.g. `0.000020615.

**So it looks like the** `toFixed` **method needs to be flexible/dynamic, e.g.** `toFixed(n)` **with a function run beforehand to determine exactly how many trailing zeros are needed?**

Here are *some* key excerpts from my current solution for your consideration:

```
function generateNum() {

do {
        genNumber = Math.random() * Math.pow (10, randomRange(-5, 5));

        //Round
        genNumber = roundToNSF(genNumber, 5, 0);

        // This number must contain >1 digit which is 1 to 9 inclusive otherwise we may have e.g. 100. Rounding 100
    } 

while (!countNonZero(genNumber) || genNumber < 1E-05 || genNumber == 0);

    //Round
    genNumber = roundToNSF(genNumber, 5, 0);


    genNumber = String(genNumber);
    genNumber = Number(genNumber);
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

function randomRange(min, max) {

/**
 * Returns a random integer between min (inclusive) and max (inclusive)
 * Using Math.round() will give you a non-uniform distribution!
 */

return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

} 

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Click SF3 Button to reveal the data
function showSF3() {

//Remove any CSS properties on the buttons from previous use
removeButtonCSS();

document.getElementById('SFRounded').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('scale').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("SF3").className = document.getElementById("SF3").className + "buttonClick";  // this removes the blue border class

//Clear text
deleteRounded();
deleteScale();

//Run calculation
calculateAnswer();

//alert(genNumber.toFixed(4));

for (i = 3; i < 4; i++)

    {
         //Add The new data
         sfRoundedTextBlock = document.getElementById('SFRounded');

         //alert(downArray[i].toFixed(4));

         //Data output to HTML.

         sfRoundedTextBlock.innerHTML = sfRoundedTextBlock.innerHTML + '<p><strong>Number: </strong></br>' + String(genNumber) + 
         '</br>' + '<strong>Rounded down to ' + i + ' SF:</br></strong>' + downArray[i] + '</br>' + 
         '<strong>Rounded up to ' + i + ' SF:</br></strong>' + upArray[i] + '</br><strong>Rounded off to ' + i + ' SF:</br></strong>' 
         + roundedArray[i] + '</br>' + '(See the scale below for why we choose <strong>' + roundedArray[i] + '</strong> as the rounded off value.)</p>';

    }

}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

var roundedArray = [];
var upArray = [];
var downArray = [];
var temp;

function calculateAnswer() {
//Clear Arrays
roundedArray = [];
upArray = [];
downArray = [];

// Work out the answer:
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

    var nSF = i + 1;
    // Round OFF ...
    temp = roundToNSF(genNumber, nSF, 0);
    // We actually have to do this twice ...
    roundedArray[nSF] = roundToNSF(temp, nSF, 0);

    // Round UP ...
    upArray[nSF] = roundToNSF(genNumber, nSF, 1);

    // Round DOWN ...
    downArray[nSF] = roundToNSF(genNumber, nSF, -1);
    // e.g. x = 0.0098 rounded to 1SF is 0.010 initially (take the log of 0.0098 and try it!).
};  
};


//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

//Globals
var aNumber;
var digits;
var way;

function roundToNSF(aNumber, digits, way){
// Round a number to n significant figures (can use roundToNDP provided we know how many decimal places):
    if (way == undefined) { way = 0; }; // default is round off

if (aNumber !=0) {

    if (aNumber > 0)
        { 
            z = log10(aNumber); 
        } 
        else 
            { 
                z = log10(-aNumber); 
            };

    z = Math.floor(z);

    var nDP = digits - z - 1; // Rounding to nDP decimal places is equivalent to rounding to digits significant figures ...

    var roundedNumber = roundToNDP(aNumber, nDP, way);

} 
else {

    roundedNumber = aNumber; // Number is zero ...
};

return Number(roundedNumber);
};

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

**Update:**

I'm still continuing to try and find a solution for this problem and an approach I have recently taken is to convert my randomly generated number into a searchable string variable and then use the `indexOf(".")` command to find the position of the **decimal point (dp)**.

Then I've searched through my number, starting from the position of the dp to find the first instance of a significant, non-zero number [1-9].

```
var genNumber =  0.097027;
var rString = String(genNumber);
var positionofDP = rString.indexOf(".");
var regexp = /[1-9]/;
var positionofNonZero = Number(rString.search(regexp, positionofDP));  // Output would be '5'
```

I have then been able to target my search further, to determine whether my first significant number has any 'problematic' zeros in the immediate digits after it.

If there are any, then I set a Boolean variable to 'true' and then in a separate function create further text strings of my rounded off/down/up numbers, so I can then physically choose to add a '0' on to the end of the existing numerical characters.

This approach does work for me in isolated cases, but with my random number length ranging from 5-12 digits long, it still isn't dealing with all scenarios.

Maybe I need to create a dynamic `toFixed(i)` function? Any ideas would be greatly welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gone away again and I think I have now finally managed solve my initial problem.

There was a degree of confusion on my part surrounding when to use `toFixed` and `toPrecision`. I had previously attempted to convert my **rounded up, down and off** numbers into strings and then subsequently search through each of these to find the decimal point `(".")` and then work out the amount of trailing numbers, in order to then generate the correct `toFixed` point.

However, this was very hit and miss, given that my random number could be up to 12 digits, so what I've now done is to properly utilise `toPrecision` instead. For each 'SF button' (1-4) I have used the corresponding `toPrecision` point, e.g for SF1:

```
    sfRoundedTextBlock.innerHTML = sfRoundedTextBlock.innerHTML + '<p><strong>Number: </strong></br>' + String(genNumber) + 
    '</br>' + '<strong>Rounded down to ' + i + ' SF:</br></strong>' + downArray[i].toPrecision(1) + '</br>' + 
    '<strong>Rounded up to ' + i + ' SF:</br></strong>' + upArray[i].toPrecision(1) + '</br><strong>Rounded off to ' + i + ' SF:</br></strong>' 
    + roundedArray[i].toPrecision(1) + '</br>' + '(See the scale below for why we choose <strong>' + roundedArray[i].toPrecision(1) + '</strong> as the rounded off value.)</p>';

    //Add The new scale data (Rounded Down)
    downTextBlock = document.getElementById('down');
    document.getElementById("down").innerHTML = String(downArray[i].toPrecision(1));

    //Add The new scale data (Rounded Up)
    upTextBlock = document.getElementById('up');
    document.getElementById("up").innerHTML = String(upArray[i].toPrecision(1));
```

This was now giving me accurate results on every occasion, but there was still one hurdle left to jump. Occasionally I would reach a random scenario where **scientific notation** would have to be included in my outputted answer, e.g. `21819` rounded down to 1 SF, would read out at `2e+4` instead of `20000`.

To combat this I setup my up, down and rounded figures into searchable strings, and then looked through these to find any illegal/scientific characters [a-z]. If I found any, I executed a slightly different version of my output which made use of `parseFloat`, which stripped out the scientific notation and displayed the correct figures:

```
//Convert Up, Down and Rounded into Strings based on their precision
        var upString = String(upArray[i].toPrecision(1));
        var downString = String(downArray[i].toPrecision(1));
        var roundedString = String(roundedArray[i].toPrecision(1));
        //Set up a regexp to search for characters [a-z], i.e. non-numeric
        var regexp = /[a-z]/g; 
        //Search the up, down and rounded strings for non-numeric characters
        var upResult = upString.match(regexp);
        var downResult = downString.match(regexp);
        var roundedResult = roundedString.match(regexp);
        //If any of these strings contain a letter (non-numeric) we need to add in parseFloat to strip away the scientific notation included.
        var containsChar = false;

        if (upResult != null || downResult != null || roundedResult != null)

            {
                containsChar = true;
                //alert("There is SN included here");
            }

         //Add The new data
         sfRoundedTextBlock = document.getElementById('SFRounded');

        if (containsChar == true)

        {
            sfRoundedTextBlock.innerHTML = sfRoundedTextBlock.innerHTML + '<p><strong>Number: </strong></br>' + String(genNumber) + 
            '</br>' + '<strong>Rounded down to ' + i + ' SF:</br></strong>' + parseFloat(downArray[i].toPrecision(1)) + '</br>' + 
            '<strong>Rounded up to ' + i + ' SF:</br></strong>' + parseFloat(upArray[i].toPrecision(1)) + '</br><strong>Rounded off to ' + i + ' SF:</br></strong>' 
            + parseFloat(roundedArray[i].toPrecision(1)) + '</br>' + '(See the scale below for why we choose <strong>' + parseFloat(roundedArray[i].toPrecision(1)) + '</strong> as the rounded off value.)</p>';

            //Add The new scale data (Rounded Down)
            downTextBlock = document.getElementById('down');
            document.getElementById("down").innerHTML = String(parseFloat(downArray[i].toPrecision(1)));

            //Add The new scale data (Rounded Up)
            upTextBlock = document.getElementById('up');
            document.getElementById("up").innerHTML = String(parseFloat(upArray[i].toPrecision(1)));
        }
```

Having tested this extensively it seems to be working as hoped.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of playing with the fixed points on an Int, you could manage the string directly.

Here's a link to a little fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5rw5G/4/

This not intended to completely/accurately solve your problem, but might help you see another solution.

```
function getRoundedSFs(num, SFCount) {    
    // Match every "leading zeros" before and after the .
    var matches = num.toString().match(/^-?(0+)\.(0*)/);

    // starting with "0."
    if (matches) { 
        var firstIndex = matches[0].length;
        var prefix = matches[0];

        sf = Number(num.toString().substring(firstIndex, firstIndex + SFCount + 1));
        sf = Math.round(sf / 10);
        sf = prefix + sf.toString();
        return Number(sf).toFixed(matches[2].length+SFCount);
    } 

    // starting with something else like -5.574487436097115
    else { 
        matches = num.toString().match(/^(-?(\d+))\.(\d+)/);
        var decimalShift = SFCount - matches[2].length;        
        var rounded = Math.round(num * Math.pow(10, decimalShift));       
        rounded /= Math.pow(10, decimalShift);
        return rounded.toFixed(decimalShift);
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is an improved version of the above code which works with bigger numbers: http://jsfiddle.net/pushrbx/c5sh29pL/